# How to keep a SSH session for dynamic forwarding alive and terminate it at will?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I found [someone](https://gist.github.com/terrywang/3983543) keeps a SSH session alive by

```
ssh -f -D $port $SSH_HOST "
    if [ -f ~/.tunnel ]; then
        rm ~/.tunnel;
    fi;
    while [ ! -f ~/.tunnel ]; do
        echo > /dev/null;
    done
" &
```

and terminates a SSH session by

```
ssh $SSH_HOST "touch ~/.tunnel"
```

1. Is the way of using a file the same way as a pid file? Can the way   be used for more or general cases?
2. Do we really need to use the way of using a file to keep a SSH session alive and terminate it? Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple Improvements**

The technique allows you to kill a connection from the remote machine.  I would suggest a couple of changes

- Add a `sleep` in the while loop, there's no point throwing CPU time on waiting
- Invert the process.  Touch the file at the start and delete it to kill the session.  This does give you an option to include a PID in the file if you want.

---

**Do you need this?**

If you only want to kill the session I would avoid the method in your question and use:

```
SSH -N -D $port $SSH_HOST &
```

This will set up a connection without a shell as a background task (`-N` disables the shell and `&` makes it a background task).

You can get the (local) PID for this with `$!` and kill it with `kill`

Eg:

```
SSH -N -D $port $SSH_HOST &
TUNNEL_PID=$!

# Do some other stuff

kill $TUNNEL_PID
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides what @PhilipCouling has written, there exists an odd but effective little utility, [Spinner,](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/spinner) useful when an interactive terminal session is to be kept open. You run it on the remote host. It doesn't do much, but sends a dummy data packet back to the local client every *N* seconds (I use *N* = 120, for example). The dummy keeps the connection alive.

Not sure that this is the sort of thing you wanted, but there it is.